# How to wait BLE callback without blocking code

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to exchange data between two BLE devices. Actually the client side is functional and my problem is in server side on IOS phone.
I create a BluetoothLEController who inherits from NSObject and CBPeripheralManagerDelegate. All parts for services, advertising, connection, subscription and `didReceiveWrite` works.

There's my problem, when I call updateValue method of CBPeripheralManager class twice or more in same time, only the first call succeeded. In Swift documentation this function return false if sending queue is busy.
I code a pseudo infinite loop like this

```
while !peripheralManager.updateValue(data,
                                     for: messageContentCharacteristic,
                                     onSubscribedCentrals: nil) {}
```

It works but it's a really bad implementation !

So after that I tried to use `DispatchSemaphore`

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
func write(_ data: Data) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        self.semaphore.wait()
        self.peripheralManager.updateValue(data,
                                           for: self.messageContentCharacteristic,
                                           onSubscribedCentrals: nil)
    }
}

func peripheralManagerIsReady(toUpdateSubscribers peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    semaphore.signal()
}
```

All threads are running. The first one call `updateValue` and my client receive notification. The other are waiting.
But, the callback `peripheralManagerIsReady#toUpdateSubscribers` is never called and my app blocks.

I'm trying different way with DispatchGroup and DispatchQueue with other priority but my problem still the same.

I hope someone can help me to be a better developper :)

Comment: Don’t use a semaphore and block. Even if it was working this approach wouldn’t help you if another update had to be sent while you were waiting to send the second. You should create a queue (using an array for example) and if you can’t send the data you add it to the queue. When the peripheral manager indicates that it is ready to send again you start processing the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paulw11 says, I implement a generic Queue based on Swift Algorithm Club. I steel use my semaphore but only for thread-safe.

```
let queue = Queue<Data>()
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

func write(_ data: Data) {
    if !peripheralManager.updateValue(data,
                                  for: messageContentCharacteristic,
                                  onSubscribedCentrals: nil) {
        semaphore.wait()
        queue.enqueue(data)
        semaphore.signal()
    }
}

func peripheralManagerIsReady(toUpdateSubscribers peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    if !queue.isEmpty {
        semaphore.wait()
        if let data = queue.dequeue() {
            peripheralManager.updateValue(data,
                                          for: messageContentCharacteristic,
                                          onSubscribedCentrals: nil)
        }
        semaphore.signal()
    }
}
```